# Advanced optimization without variable mangling

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I want to compile some JavaScript with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS but without mangling variables, I cannot find anything in the docs on how to config it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to debug something `--debug` with the pretty print option works pretty well.  If you want to disable it entirely, you need to use the Java API as it isn't exposed to via the command-line. The specific option is:

[CompilerOptions#setRenamingPolicy](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/6b789dba67731dd49a93ab387a667b0507413b04/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#L1584)

If you are using type based optimizations, you may also want to disable them and they (ambiguate and disambiguate properties) also rename properties.

Basic information on using the Java API can be found in the projects wiki  [Using the Compiler's Java API](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Using-the-Compiler's-Java-API)

For myself, I usually just patch the compiler's current command-line runner to set the options that I want.